# String functions in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Emp (id, name)  
values(10, `RAMESH`)
      (20, `MAHESH`)
      (30, `KIRAN`)
```

Output:

```
RamesH  
MahesH
KiraN
```

How to write a query to get this output?

Comment: read a tutorial to start.  here is one: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: are you asking for the query `SELECT name FROM Emp WHERE id = 10`?  If so you should go and study SQL -- read a book, website or take a class -- this kind of question is way to low level for this site -- you are assumed to understand the basics you would get in the first day of a class

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM Emp WHERE id = 10
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp

Comment: id = 10 will give only `RAMESH`

Comment: Remove the where clause. SELECT name FROM Emp @H.DJEMAI